# Apache configured incorrectly. PHP showing as plain text

Tags: php, apache, vagrant

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to get this project up an running. I've inherited a project that was written a couple of years ago. It took me quite a while to figure out the VagrantFile and get the vm up and running. Now I'm running into the problem that my php is displaying as plain text.

I can't tell if it's an apache config problem or something with the rewrite rules.

Any help would be appreciated and I can provide more info if needed.

It's a vagrant box ubuntu/trusty64 (14.04).

In my vagrant file I've synched the folders as follows:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",:mount_options=>["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
```

This is my conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                         
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                        
ServerName 192.168.34.50.xip.io                                        

DocumentRoot /vagrant                                                  


<Directory /vagrant>                                                   
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews                       
    AllowOverride All                                                  
    Require all granted                                                
    Allow from all                                                     
    <FilesMatch \.php$>                                                
        # Change this "proxy:unix:/path/to/fpm.socket"                 
        # if using a Unix socket                                       
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"                       
    </FilesMatch>                                                      
</Directory>                                                           

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/192.168.34.50.xip.io-error.log              

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,     
# alert, emerg.                                                        
LogLevel warn                                                          

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/192.168.34.50.xip.io-access.log combined
```

I'm not too sure what the FilesMatch section does so I believe that might be something?

Comment: Have you already tried the answers in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: Yea, when restarting apache after adding the loadmodule line I get a message saying the module is already loaded. Adding the addtype has no affect.